# How do you copy PGN from the chess.com iPhone app?

Tags: chess.com

I'm on wondering how to copy/paste the PGN from a game played on the chess.com iPhone app. How do you do it? NB: without logging into the website or using any device other than the chess.com iPhone app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take up the menu in the bottom left corner of the completed game, press "share" and then "copy" and you should then be able to paste it wherever you want.